# C How to get number of players and their names

Tags: c

Hi am trying to learn how to program and i would like the user to input how many players there are as well as their first names. i thought i was correct with my following code after watching some youtube videos and looking elsewhere online but i cannot see where i have gone wrong. if someone could please help that would be awesome.

```
int main() {
  int i, player_num; 
  char names[8][25];

  printf("\n\n");  

  //user inputs value of player_num, here, as you have now


  for(i = 0; i < player_num; i++) {
    printf("Enter the player's name: ");
    scanf("%s", names[i]);  //enters name and creates a newline <enter key>
    getchar();                   //removes the newline from the keyboard buffer
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  for(i = 0; i < player_num; i++)
    printf("\n%s", names[i]);

  printf("\n\n\t\t\t     press enter when ready");

  getchar();   //holds the console window open until you press enter
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Enter number of players (1-8)\n"); scanf("%d", &player_num);`

Comment: You might want to do something like `player_num=0; while(player_num < 1 || player_num > 8) { printf("Enter number of players (1-8)\n"); scanf("%d", &player_num); }` This will prompt the user again if they enter a bad number.

Comment: Beginner programs frequently do a little dialog with user via stdin. This is actually quite a tricky thing to get right, and scanf() doesn't work like most C functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enter the number of player. It seems that you have already written code for entering players name. So for entering number of Player you need to use one `scanf()`

```
int main() 
{
   int i, player_num; 
   char names[8][25];
   printf("\n\n");  
//user inputs value of player_num, here, as you have now
   printf("Enter the number of player(from 1 to 8)\n");
   scanf_s("%d",&player_num,sizeof(int));
   for(i = 0; i < player_num; i++) {
     printf("Enter the player's name: ");
     scanf_s("%s", names[i],25);  //enters name and creates a newline <enter key>
     getchar();               //removes the newline from the keyboard buffer
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   for(i = 0; i < player_num; i++)
      printf("\n%s", names[i]);
   printf("\n\n\t\t\t     press enter when ready");
   getchar();   //holds the console window open until you press enter
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Thank you but my program crashes after i enter the users name plus i would like to enter a name for all user it seems to only want one name then it crashes and ask if i want to debug the program

Comment: @ElijahCeeney I ran it in my system it is working fine. you might have done some typo. check again

Comment: i did what program did you use? i was using visual studio

Comment: @ElijahCeeney yeap i am also using Visual Studio.

Comment: @ElijahCeeney first of all you need to enter how many number of players you want. so first enter any number from 1 to 8. then start typing names. If you start typing name first, then it will crash.

Comment: I did enter the number of players first it is then when i proceed to enter the names it crashes.

Comment: it runs like a charm in my Visual Studio. I don't know what is causing your program to crash. You try copying my code and running it in your IDE.

Comment: Yes i copied it exactly

Comment: Nope crashes after i enter the first name

Comment: you are using `scanf_s()` just use `scanf()`

Comment: posted everything below

Comment: i need to use scanf_s as it is a requirement for the course

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in question. after using scanf_s even my program is crashing

Comment: sorry i am new i didnt see how it would cause it to crash i just assumed that the input would be the same.